# Are we no longer in beta?

Tags: discussion

Are we no longer in the beta period? The 'Software Recommendations beta' logo is now 'Software Recommendations'.

[Yesterday (14 July '14)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140714163342/https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

[Today (15 July '14)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

If so, great!! But I thought I'd ask, as it is still 'Public Beta' on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations)

Comment: Looks like that's either just for you, or my browser kept the "old logo" in cache: I still have the "beta" displayed. *Refreshing* Oh, gone? Congrats to us, we've made it! Sympathy to most of us who lost some privileges (except for Franck who made it in time…)

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately not!

Comment: I'm not unlucky about the "not". Need some more rep before that – and this site certainly needs some more high-rep users before we graduate! Currently, we've just got one 10k+ member. To stay operatable without overloading our mods, we should have at least 3 of those. So keep on upvoting! :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, a certain number of "high-rep users" is one condition for a site to graduate (for the given reasons, I assume). One point for me to push Franck even when he surpassed me in rep :) (usually, that would mean the "sportmanship" badge, but our answers were on different questions ;)

Comment: @Izzy lol, yes, I wish the site gets more high-rep users ASAP. This was a good Area51 proposal!

Comment: Heh, saw this in the little new-meta-posts thing and got really excited. Then saw that it was a bug :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, it was [a glitch in the matrix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236564/did-all-sites-just-graduate). We have not yet graduated, and this was apparently precipitated by a unicorn eating the wires.

There is nothing to see here, please move along.

If all goes well, the imaginary [status-planned](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag will get changed to [status-completed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), rather than [status-declined](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: oh... :'( I was happy! I thought we'd finally reached there! Why say `If all goes well`? Say `When all goes well`! (if that makes sense :)

Comment: Since the dev team uses the [status-*] tags to find and track feature requests and bugs, using the status-planned tag here is not appropriate.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I'll remember that in future.